# Is it possible for R/exams to export exercises to Blackboard using $$ for Latex equations?

Tags: r, latex, r-exams

I want to use R/exams to produce Blackboard quizzes for a physics course. However, there is a problem with the display of equations within Blackboard. MathML output does not reproduce clearly on different browsers (e.g., square root signs are fine on Firefox but mangled on Safari and absent on Chrome) and my institution prefers I not use MathJax.

Blackboard is able to correctly display LaTeX equations written within the text using the `$$` delimiter e.g., `$$a_n =\sqrt{2}$$`. So my question is whether `exams2blackboard` can output for Blackboard in a way that preserves the LaTeX for equations within the text but adds the $$? Or whether there's another way of achieving this using R/exams?

Answer (score 0):

*Preserving LaTeX:* When you have `$$...$$` markup in your code, then plain pandoc will preserve this in the conversion to HTML provided that there are math elements that it cannot emulate in plain HTML. This would be the case for `\sqrt{...}` for example while `x^2` would simply be emulated. So you can experiment with this using `exams2blackboard(..., converter = "pandoc-quiet")`. I'm not sure that it works though - haven't got access to Blackboard for testing.

*Adding $$:* To the best of my knowledge this is not provided by pandoc and I wouldn't know how to work around this in R/exams.

*Rendering MathML:* This is generally not available on Chrome, so it isn't surprising that Chrome doesn't handle square roots etc. In Safari MathML should usually work ok, I wouldn't be aware that it generally has problems with square roots - but we definitely saw occasional problems on Safari. Firefox is the only mainstream browser with really excellent MathML support.

*In summary:* If the first option above does not work well enough for your, then I would recommend to either require students to use Firefox - or to include MathJax in the exercises. If your institution does not want you to include MathJax, maybe there is a way to generally provide MathJax inside Blackboard for them?

Comment: Thanks. I'll experiment with that and report back.